# Windows authentication trough Identity Server 4

Tags: authentication, identityserver4

I have tried to find but without any success on how to use Windows authentication that is implemented in IdentityServer4 samples (Quickstart6: AspNetIdentity).

What I managed to find out is that I can use http://localhost:5000/connect/token to POST client_id, client_secret, scope and grant_type in order to get token. The issue is next. From what I have managed to find out in order to use Windows authentication, I need to use "hybrid" for grant_type, but I always get "unsupported_grant_type".

Since I want to avoid default MVC client that is in that example to work with Windows authentication, how can I use Windows authentication trough rest with provided username/email and password, so I can make my own login page for Windows authentication in for example React application?

I have also found http://localhost:5000/connect/authorize endpoint, but I don't know if I can use it for this and how to even work with that endpoint.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest reading more about OpenID connect in general to familiarise yourself with the various flows.

When working in a Windows context I'd recommend using ADFS. The latest version supports OpenID Connect out of the box so is a doddle to integrate with from ASP.Net Core whereas the other options (direct LDAP calls or IIS integration) are more complex and/or restrictive.

That said, this article covers how to use integrated Windows auth when running in IIS on Windows: https://docs.identityserver.io/en/release/topics/windows.html